# Very simple question about subsets

Tags: statistics, elementary-set-theory

Is $\{1, 2, 2, 3\}$ a subset of $\{1, 2, 3\}$ because all of the elements in $\{1, 2, 2, 3\}$ are contained in $\{1, 2, 3\}$? 
However, $\{1, 2, 2, 3\}$ isn't part of the power set of $\{1, 2, 3\}$, right? 
Thanks!

Comment: {1,2,2,3} is the same as saying {1,2,3}.

Comment: Every set is a subset of itself and therefore a member of the power set as well.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know how to prove two sets are equal? Prove {1,2,3} is a subset of {1,2,2,3} and {1,2,2,3} is a subset of {1,2,3}.  {1,2,3} is a subset of {1,2,2,3} since every member of {1,2,3} is in {1,2,2,3} and {1,2,2,3} is a subset of {1,2,3} since every member of {1,2,2,3} is in {1,2,3}. Therefore, {1,2,3}={1,2,2,3}. Writing {1,2,2,3} is kinda redundant since a member is being listed twice. {1,2,2,3} only has 3 members. The three members are 1,2, and 3. I hope that this shows you why they are the same sets. Or at least convinces you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is $\{1, 2, 2, 3\}$ a subset of $\{1, 2, 3\}$ because all of the elements in $\{1, 2, 2, 3\}$ are contained in $\{1, 2, 3\}$?

Yes. Since multiplicity of elements makes no difference, they are the same set, so trivially they are also subsets of each other.

> However, $\{1, 2, 2, 3\}$ isn't part of the power set of $\{1, 2, 3\}$, right?

If by "part of" you mean "element of", then yes, it is. Again: They are the same set, so they have the same powerset, and every set is an element -- but not a subset -- of its own powerset.